# Google sheets API: How to retrieve the A1 notation of an active range with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm actually working on a web project based on Google Spreadsheet, and following the Browser quickstart method (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

I would like to select a range on my sheet, and click on a button.
I would have a function that detect the active range's A1 notation, then stores it in a variable and display it in an input range. 
Many people that are using the script editor are talkig about a "getActiveRange" function. But this function is only accessible when using the script editor, and not from my js file.

Is there another way to get the A1 notation of my selected range?

Answer (score 1):

Using Sheets API, what you're asking isn't straight up available. Like what you've mentioned, this is somewhat doable using App Script's [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange) but for Sheets APIv4, there's no ad-hoc to do that. The only supported methods in Sheets API  v4 is found in the official [reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. You need to develop your own little function to calculate the A1 Notation. If someone knows something better, please let me know ☺️

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to select a Range with the **spreadsheets.values.get** Method, take a look here:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

Does that help you?

Comment: Not really. I've already used the spreadsheets.values.get Method. 
In the "Range" parameter, I have to enter the A1 notation myself, and the method returns the datas of the the selected range.
What I'd like to do is selecting a range on the sheet with the mouse, and have the matching A1 notation displayed in my input range. 
The best exemple I have is the Add on XLMiner.